# Laravel File cache vs MySQL primary key search

Tags: mysql, laravel, caching

Does it matter to use laravel file cache for queries like: `select * from table where id = ?` ?
Which is fastest way?

Comment: with id as a primary key this will be extremely fast, so why cache it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the system you are designing. If you want to reduce repetitive database queries and reduce the load on database, then you can cache the queries.